# Adding my domain's email in gmail for "Send mail as" gmail feature

Tags: server, email, postfix, gmail

I have email set up on my Ubuntu server and when I do `dig mydomain.com mx` the output is:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com.       86400   IN  MX  10 mail.mydomain.com.
```

Now when I'm using gmail, I want to be able to change to reply from myusername@mydomain.com. I've set this up before with a Hostgator domain I had in the past. The setting in gmail is show below:

[image]

But I keep getting the following error when trying to add my new domain (hosted through a VPS with linode):

[image]

Keep in mind that I am an extreme beginner in server set up, so assume I know nothing in your answer if possible. I notice that gmail is asking for a password, but I don't remember ever setting a password for an email account on my server. I basically just installed postfix and set up a virtual map which forwards all incoming mail to my gmail account (which works fine by the way).

Also, I have already tried ports 465 and 587 too.