# setup sendmail smtp to add use it as gmail alias

Tags: gmail, sendmail

I installed sendmail and dovecot and I am able to send and receive emails from mutt as mail@myowndomain.com. I want to be able to add this account to gmail as alias, to send and receive mails via webbrowser.

I tried to setup sendmail to use myowndomain.com as external smtp but it didnt work.

What should I do now?

Each time I try to add it to gmail I get new error in log :

```
sm-mta[14600]: uACF7Fwr014600: mail-wm0-f53.google.com [74.125.82.53] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MSP-v4
```

Edit:
In gmail in settings there is a tab "accounts and import". There you can add "another address you own". To do this you need server address, mail, username, password and port. I tried many combinations, yet I'm not able to add it. Always ends in error.

The purpose of this is that I will be able to log into my gmail, compose new mail and send it (or receive) as mail@mydomain.com. I've done that with my hotmail address and my university mail. I also have one root@mydomain.com which was a leftover from times when I tried to setup postfix. This one almost works: I can send mail as root from web browser, but when I want to receive this email it is only accesible on server via mutt. I tried to replicate this entry using serveruser@mydomain.com but failed.

My understanding of 'relay' is that my server sends mails through my gmail account. I dont want that. I just want serveruser@mydomain.com was in the FROM header of mails I send from browser's gmail (not mymail@gmail.com) and to be able to receive mails sent to serveruser@mydomain.com in browser's gmail.

Comment: You want to be able to forward the mail automatically to your gmail?

Comment: No, not forward. Something like this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/626528/adding-my-domains-email-in-gmail-for-send-mail-as-gmail-feature

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps, here I was using postfix though. [Setup Mail Transport Agent Using Ubuntu and Gmail | Do It Yourself in Ubuntu Blog](https://ubuntudiy.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/setup-mail-transport-agent-mta-using-ubuntu-and-gmail/)

Comment: Nope. First it uses postfix. I tried postfix few months back and it was total failure. As I remember, and comapring with this tutorial it ends in a way where you send mail from server AS from gmail account. Thats not what I want

Comment: I cannot quite understand your question. You have a private mail server that works (mydomain.com) and you also have a gmail account. Can you explain how do you expect the aliasing to work?

Comment: Sure, I update question then.